# Form not submitting POST

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I have this form in my Spring Boot/Thymeleaf/Bootstrap application:

```
<form action="/person" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button></form>
```

Now the issue is that when I submit the form it just makes a GET request to "/?" url instead of POSTing to "/person".

What could be the reason for that behavior?

Comment: you cannot post this form to the specified path as `/person` the form action only accepts the url like `person.php` or `person.html`

Comment: try setting the method to `method="post"` (small) instead of `method="POST"`(caps)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/person" method="post">
     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
     </div>
     <input type="submit" class="form-submit">
 </form>
```